# log4net not working on selfhosted wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, service, log4net

i wrote a c# client- server application using wcf.
client and server are working fine. i added logging with log4net to my wcf service.

whene i start my service in visual studio, logging works fine. but whene i use my console application to host my wcfservice, nothing is logged. the wcfservice is running correctly and is accessable.

here my config part in my app.config on the wcfservice project:

```
  <log4net xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:log4net">
<root>
  <level value="INFO"/>
  <appender-ref ref="name="FileAppender"/>
</root>
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <file value="d:\\_serverLib.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="INFO" />
    <levelMax value="FATAL" />
  </filter>
</appender>
```

following line is added to the assambyinfo.cs of my wcfservice:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

every class that is using log4net has its reference to the logger:

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

where is my fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your config is set up correctly and accessible to the app, it's probably [this as stated in the documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#attributes):

> Using attributes can be a clearer method for defining where the
>   application's configuration will be loaded from. However it is worth
>   noting that attributes are purely passive. They are information only.
>   Therefore if you use configuration attributes you must invoke log4net
>   to allow it to read the attributes. A simple call to
>   LogManager.GetLogger will cause the attributes on the calling assembly
>   to be read and processed. **Therefore it is imperative to make a logging
>   call as early as possible during the application start-up, and
>   certainly before any external assemblies have been loaded and invoked**.

So you need to call `LogManager.GetLogger` in the main program of the console app before loading the WCF service (you don't actually have to log anything)

Comment: This seems that the calling program would do the logging not the wcf service

Comment: @Demodave this is about initialisation of the log system not the actual logging

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes across this issue and cannot find a resolution, what my problem was that I had added log4net from nuget when my project was set to .NET 4.5.1.  I had to back my project down to .NET 4.5 - but log4net was still trying to use 4.5.1.  I had to change the value in packages.config:

```
<package id="log4net" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

This resolved the issue for me.